# Prevent dock/plank and top bar from showing up when terminal or system app is opened

Tags: 16.04, dock, plank

Is there any way to prevent dock (plank) and top bar from showing up while terminal or any system app is opened? Whem I use google chrome or some spotify or VS Code dock and top bar is hidden but when I open terminal or files or trash both of them appear and stay visible until I exit those apps.
I use ubuntu 16.04 with plank.

Comment: For Plank this should be arranged through the settings of Planck. With respect to top bar, how do you hide it? By default this cannot be hidden,

Comment: I'm using gnome tool tweaks and some extensions. Both dock and top bar shows when I enter mouse there. Didn't see such option in plank preferences :(

Comment: Chances of help might increase if you edit your post to provide all relevant information. Now, people cannot even attempt to reproduce your problem, leave alone solve it. If you indicate that you use extensions, then I think of Gnome Shell. Yet, you use 16.04 and that by default comes with Unity. You see: confusion everywhere.